# Cartesian Hyperbolic Plane Geodesics

Tags: metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry, euler-lagrange-equation

Let the ordered pair $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be the unique point in the hyperbolic plane arrived at by starting at [an arbitrary point called the origin] and going [east, an arbitrarily chosen direction] distance $x$ followed by going [north, an arbitrarily chosen direction perpendicular to east] distance $y$. $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$ are hyperbolic distances. Every point in the hyperbolic plane can be reached in this method.
A little work showed that the metric of the plane is
$$(ds)^2=(\cosh(y)*dx)^2+(dy)^2$$
Let $y=g(x)$ be a geodesic. Then the Euler-Lagrange formula leads to the equation
$$\tanh(g(x))(\cosh(g(x))^2+2g'(x)^2)=g''(x)$$
Also, $y=\pm g(\pm x-c)$ is a geodesic for $c\in\mathbb{R}$, as can be seen by the symmetry of the metric.

All geodesics can be divided into 4 types of geodesics:

The trivial case $y=0$.

Those that do not cross the x-axis, looking similar to $c_0\sec(c_2(x-c_1))$.
$$g_0(0)\in\mathbb{R}^+,g_0'(0)=0,g_0(x)=g_0(-x),y=\pm g_0(x-c_0),c_0\in\mathbb{R}$$

Those that cross the x-axis, looking similar to $c_0\tan(c_2(x-c_1))$.
$$g_1(0)=0,g_1'(0)\in\mathbb{R}^+,g_1(x)=-g_1(-x),y=\pm g_1(x-c_1),c_1\in\mathbb{R}$$

Those that touch the x-axis once infinitely far from the origin. $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}g_2(x)=0,\lim_{h\to\infty}g_2(-1/h)=\infty,y=\pm g_2(\pm x-c_2),c_2\in\mathbb{R}$$

Please help find the formulae for $g_k(x)$ in these 3 non-trivial cases.

More details on the derivation of the metric and of the Euler-Lagrange result are [here](https://github.com/Nazgand/nazgandMathBook/blob/master/HyperbolicPlaneMetrics.pdf).

Comment: It would help if you started out by highlighting the model you're working in. Also, are your distances $x$ and $y$ measured in hyperbolic metric or in the Euclidean model? An image of the two cases you refer to would also be useful.

Comment: What does it mean to "go north/east in the hyperbolic plane?" Also, I do not know about your formula but geodesics in Riemannian manifolds do not have singularities. Lastly, why do you work in this model? In all three standard Riemannian models on the hyperbolic plane geodesics are easy to describe and this was discussed many times at MSE.

Comment: I am working in pure hyperbolic geometry, and giving each point Cartesian coordinates. The distances x and y are hyperbolic distances. An image is in the linked PDF and is used to derive the general metric for $ds$.
'East' is any direction you choose, and 'north' is any direction you choose which is perpendicular to east.
What I meant by singularities is that the geodesics go to an infinite y value within a finite x value.
The reason I work in this model is that it is intuitive to me and useful for imagining certain tilings of the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deduced the formula for $g_1(x)$ first. It merely required some simple [right-angle hyperbolic trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_triangle#Trigonometry_of_right_triangles).
I must admit that I guessed and checked for finding the other 2 types geodesics; so I can only say it was intuition for guessing and the Euler-Lagrange formula for checking.

Those that do not cross the x-axis.
$$g_0(x)=artanh(\tanh(g_0(0))\cosh(x)),|x|<arcosh(\tanh(g_0(0))^{-1})$$

Those that cross the x-axis.
$$g_1(x)=artanh(g_1'(0)\sinh(x)),|x|<arsinh(g_1'(0)^{-1})$$

Those that touch the x-axis once infinitely far from the origin.
$$g_2(x)=artanh(\exp(x)),x<0$$